# How can I run eslint in a subdirectory using GitHub Actions when there is a .eslintrc file in the parent directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, continuous-integration, github-actions, eslint

I am creating a workflow in GitHub Actions (node.js). I have separate workflows in my GitHub repository for each folder that has a separate application. In each workflow I run eslint for each application.

The problem that I have is that when I run eslint it uses the eslintrc file of the parent directory, not the subdirectory (working directory) that I am running the test on.

The error has only occured now as the parent directory has a vue plugin which the other applications (folders) use, but this particular application does not and I get an error.

Here is the part of my workflow yml file that deals with eslint so far:

```
    - run: npm run lint -- --config=./child/.eslintrc.js
      working-directory: ./child
```

I have also tried this in my package-json file:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs --fix -c ./.eslintrc.js",
    "test": "node --test"
  },
```

(I have also tried variations of same!)

Is there a way to direct GitHub Actions to the child directory's .eslintrc file?